# React-Bootstrap-Rails Modal show error

Tags: reactjs

I have problem with render react-bootstrap Modal on my Rails application.

Here is the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'findDOMNode' of undefined

Code:

```
<Modal show="true"></Modal>
```